# ConstraintException after EnforceConstraints in C# datasets

Tags: c#, typed-dataset

Based on pseudo-code from below could you please tell me if can I do somethig like this or it will be better to reload my dataset in case of constraint failure?

Thanks!

```
var myDataSet = new DataTypedDataset(); // the dataset has some tables with ParentChild and ForeightKey relationships
try{
      myDataset.EnforceConstraints = false;
      LoadDataset(meDataset); // some method that fills the schema by data that violates given schema constraints
      myDataset.EnforceConstraints = true;
}
catch(ConstraintException ce){
      LogConstraintException(ce);//some logging
      myDataset.EnforceConstraints = false;
}


// suppose I have A = {1}, B = { {A=2, 2}, {A=1,2}}
try{
      var aRow = myDataset.TableB.First().ARow; 
}
catch(??/*What type of the exception will be here?*/ exception)
{
  // hm... pitty
  letsPlayFailureTollerantScenario(myDataset.TableB.First(), myDataset.TableA);
}

var rows = myDataset.TableA.GetBRows();
```

Answer (score 0):

So after some tests it turned out that it is technically possible. But to be honest I would be  happier if the task was more strict in regards of data constraints, because finding a an error in under such implemetation is not a peace of cake.